# How to restore/re-create some folders from Time Machine backup of a different computer?

Tags: time-machine, backup, restore

I have Time Machine backup of computer A, a Macbook Pro mid-2010. I want to restore/re-create some folders backed up in that backup on a different computer, a Macbook Pro Retina mid-2014.  How to *properly* do this?

Answer (score -1):

You can use Migration Assistant.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, however, can you add details as to how this solves the problem?